# How to apply Media Queries to Cards with Images

Tags: html, css, media-queries

been trying to media query my cards + image, for a while now without success, if anyone can guide me through I'll appreciate it a lot thanks.

Testing it on my phone samsung s9+ vertically.

https://codepen.io/picklemyrickle/pen/XWjzyvb

```css
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #prices {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .listdrop {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .casual {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}

#prices {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.listdrop {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border: 1px solid;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/JH3M2ZropJUZvOoL6IgHOrnZUz3cIEw5taJuPA2N_wyEHmr2hSBOOZHjGX05Q9wJ7DBXaQ8ABvG2rInPk7seHBVf8voG5ePyFXWY-7ciIcrpw_v7w23j6HV856fsSTKuwMpYDg1YDQ=w2400" alt="Gym logo" id="header-img">

<section id="prices">

  <!-- <div class="beginner"> -->
  <ul class="listdrop">
    <li class="card-head">Beginner</li>

    <li>Get Big</li>
    <li>Get Strong</li>
    <li>Feel good</li>
    <li class="pay">100$</li>

    <li type="button" class="butn" a href="#">Buy</a>
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- </div> -->
  <div class="casual">
    <ul class="listdrop">
      <li class="card-head">Casual</li>

      <li>Get Big</li>
      <li>Get Strong</li>
      <li>Feel good</li>
      <li class="pay">200$</li>


      <li type="button" class="butn" a href="#">Buy</a>
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- <div class="intermidate"> -->

  <ul class="listdrop">
    <li class="card-head">Intermidate</li>

    <li>Get Big</li>
    <li>Get Strong</li>
    <li>Feel good</li>
    <li class="pay">300$</li>

    <li class="butn" type="button" a href="#">Buy</a>
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!--  </div> -->

</section>
```

I tried changing the html, played with the CSS, without success on my own. other elements seem wide enough and works fine besides the card, I tried adding a div element as well after the section but it seems to screw my cards. With IMG I seem to be more lost, horizontally I can see the icon just much smaller, but vertically nothing, I guess because the screen isn't as wide vertically as horizontally but I'm not sure what is the solution for that.

Comment: Please note, that you have multiple HTML markup issues which are either invalid or caused by typos. `<li type="button" class="butn" a href="#">` as example.  Note that `button` is not a valid HTML attribute. Also a button within a link or vice versa is not valid either. Two media queries with both the same rule are superfluous.

Comment: I'ts not clear to me the question exaxctly, but you mention images are hard, you should wrap them in a div container you can handle through queries too. horizontal scaling is usually the easy part. There are also css flexboxes you could use, but really, its hard to nail down your actual issue

Comment: There are frameworks that will do this for you, but if you're trying to figure it out, they might also prove as a good learning tool.. Bootstrap is one, if you look at v3 documenation on how they managed it, it might clear some things up. You're already using the framework.. Might aswell learn how it works.

Comment: The MQs just set width to 100% ... so your problem is you want to rearrange things so the cards at the bottom are stacked?

Comment: My problem is #1 the logo not seen vertically on my phone.
#2 the cards not looking good from the phone, ain't wide enough.

What I'll try to do for now is fix the html, and I'll go from there.